# How to get all the class objects by attributes in python

Tags: python, list, class, sorting

I have a list of objects representing rooms in a building, each object has attributes like area, category etc. I know i can use sort() to sort the list by a specific attribute, but how would I go around sorting objects by a specific attribute and create separate lists containing objects with the same value in the attribute? For example one list with all the objects with category attribute = "private" and another with "public" etc

Comment: maybe you should use dictionary

Comment: Take a look at the [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) function.

Answer (score 0):

This would work.

```
private_List = []
for obj in List:
    if hasattr(obj, "private"):
        private_List.append(obj)
```